# SharePoint Online Access Request Status Codes

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

I am using CSOM to retrieve items from the "Access Requests" list.

(https://sharepointSite.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Access%20Requests/pendingreq.aspx)

I am trying to figure out all the possible values of the "Status" field.

I have found the following values (just from looking at the access requests page and comparing to the data retrieved from my code)

- 0 = Pending
- 2 = Accepted
- 5 = Withdrawn

I have been unable to find any reference to these codes online. Can anyone point me to a reference for these values or let me know what you figured our on your own?

**EDIT:**
This is for the status of invitations (in the access request list) - not the moderation status of people requesting access.  When I "share" the site, the invitation ends up in the access requests list with the IsInvitation bit set to true.  Please see image below where I point out the IsInvitation and Status fields.  I am looking for the possible values/meanings for Status (not moderation status).

This image shows a status of 5 for an invite that has been withdrawn.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Statuses are stored in `Approval Status` field (`Internal Name: _ModerationStatus`) for the specified `Access Requests` list

How to retrieve values of `_ModerationStatus` field via CSOM

```
var listTitle = "Access Requests";
var fieldName = "_ModerationStatus";
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
ctx.Load(field);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var fieldChoice = ctx.CastTo<FieldChoice>(field);
var values = fieldChoice.Choices;
foreach (var value in values)
{
     Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

**Result**

```
0;#Approved
1;#Rejected
2;#Pending
3;#Draft
4;#Scheduled
```

**About Moderation Status field**

According to [2.2.1.2.13 Moderation Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh644558(v=office.12).aspx) the following are all possible valid values for Moderation Status:

> - 0 - The list item is approved.
> - 1 - The list item has been denied approval.
> - 2 - The list item is pending approval.
> - 3 - The list item is in the draft or checked out state.
> - 4 - The list item is scheduled for automatic approval at a future    date.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Please see my edits above, as I am looking for info on "status", not "moderation status".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

OK whilst "_ModerationStatus" values are 0..4 (where 0=Approved), this is not the same as the "Status" field of an Access Request, which has values I have obtained from the Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAccessRequestsUtility (public enum StatusToInt), as well as accessrequestsviewtemplate.debug.js file (located in 15 hive, Layouts folder):

- 0=Pending (which could also trigger expired is an invitation)
- 1=Approved
- 2=Accepted
- 3=Denied
- 4=Expired
- 5=Revoked

I obtained this from powershell hitting the field and obtaining the SchemaXml property, reverse-engineering code as well as [this MS link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj675013(v=office.12).aspx)

Also look at these links depending upon your need:

1. [article 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaccessrequests.changerequeststatus.aspx)
2. [article 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj674880(v=office.12).aspx)

Copied here for someone also looking for this.

[Reference for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853422/sharepoint-online-access-request-status-codes)